# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory" not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\website\excel.php:4

Tags: php, xampp, phpspreadsheet

I Installed PhpSpreadsheet Using this command
`composer require phpoffice/phpspreadsheet` 
and i run example codes in documentation and got error
for example this code:

```
<?php
$inputFileName = './sampleData/example1.xls';

/** Load $inputFileName to a Spreadsheet Object  **/
$spreadsheet = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::load($inputFileName);
?>
```

I checked installed directory and this files exist :

```
    Directory: C:\xampp\htdocs\website\vendor\phpoffice\phpspreadsheet

Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name                                                                 
----                 -------------         ------ ----                                                                 
d-----         8/31/2023   5:25 PM                src                                                                  
-a----         6/14/2023   3:48 PM          11084 .php-cs-fixer.dist.php                                               
-a----         6/14/2023   3:48 PM            752 .phpcs.xml.dist                                                                                                                     
-a----         6/14/2023   3:48 PM         112316 CHANGELOG.md                                                         
-a----         6/14/2023   3:48 PM           3799 composer.json                                                        
-a----         6/14/2023   3:48 PM           3136 CONTRIBUTING.md                                                      
-a----         6/14/2023   3:48 PM           1079 LICENSE                                                              
-a----         6/14/2023   3:48 PM           1076 phpstan-baseline.neon                                                
-a----         6/14/2023   3:48 PM           4101 phpstan-conditional.php                                              
-a----         6/14/2023   3:48 PM           1374 phpstan.neon.dist                                                    
-a----         6/14/2023   3:48 PM            617 phpunit10.xml.dist                                                   
-a----         6/14/2023   3:48 PM           6667 README.md
```

and this directory :

```
    Directory: C:\xampp\htdocs\website\vendor\phpoffice\phpspreadsheet\src\PhpSpreadsheet


Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name                                                                 
----                 -------------         ------ ----                                                                 
d-----         8/31/2023   5:25 PM                Calculation                                                          
d-----         8/31/2023   5:25 PM                Cell                                                                 
d-----         8/31/2023   5:25 PM                Chart                                                                
d-----         8/31/2023   5:25 PM                Collection                                                           
d-----         8/31/2023   5:25 PM                Document                                                             
d-----         8/31/2023   5:25 PM                Helper                                                               
d-----         8/31/2023   5:25 PM                Reader                                                               
d-----         8/31/2023   5:25 PM                RichText                                                             
d-----         8/31/2023   5:25 PM                Shared                                                               
d-----         8/31/2023   5:25 PM                Style                                                                
d-----         8/31/2023   5:25 PM                Worksheet                                                            
d-----         8/31/2023   5:25 PM                Writer                                                                                                                             
-a----         6/14/2023   3:48 PM           4358 CellReferenceHelper.php                                              
-a----         6/14/2023   3:48 PM           7531 Comment.php                                                          
-a----         6/14/2023   3:48 PM           6567 DefinedName.php                                                      
-a----         6/14/2023   3:48 PM             83 Exception.php                                                        
-a----         6/14/2023   3:48 PM           3846 HashTable.php                                                        
-a----         6/14/2023   3:48 PM            182 IComparable.php                                                      
-a----         6/14/2023   3:48 PM           9020 IOFactory.php                                                        
-a----         6/14/2023   3:48 PM            973 NamedFormula.php                                                     
-a----         6/14/2023   3:48 PM           1250 NamedRange.php                                                       
-a----         6/14/2023   3:48 PM          55334 ReferenceHelper.php                                                  
-a----         6/14/2023   3:48 PM           6145 Settings.php                                                         
-a----         6/14/2023   3:48 PM          46390 Spreadsheet.php                                                      
-a----         6/14/2023   3:48 PM           7171 Theme.php
```

i tried to reinstall but got this error again

Comment: Do you have the usual `require` and `use` for the PHPSpreadsheet library at the top of your PHP code? I've only used it once, but I have `require "vendor/autoload.php";` followed by `use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;` and `use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx;` - I don't use Composer, though, so I'm not sure if that makes any difference.

Comment: What makes you think that this problem is related to XAMPP after all? What have you tried to resolve it?